# NodeJS Buffer.write() returns 0 when writing to an index >= 100,000

Tags: javascript, node.js, data-structures, buffer, nodes

```
main.js
        global.buff = Buffer.alloc(100010)
        global.index = 0

buffer.js
        bytes_written = global.buff.write(data, global.buff_idx)
        global.buff_idx += bytes_written
```

In nodeJS, Buffer.write() usually returns number of bytes that were written to the buffer.
When I try writing to any index >= 100,000, it returns 0. I read that the max buffer size is 1GB (32-bit) and 2GB (64-bit) so I don't believe that would be an issue.

The log says:

```
index before: 95142  offset: 1605  index after: 96747
index before: 96747  offset: 2195  index after: 98942
index before: 98942  offset: 1058  index after: 100000
index before: 100000 offset: 0     index after: 100000
index before: 100000 offset: 0     index after: 100000
```

Comment: Is `globa.buff` a typo?  And, was it you who just wrote a nearly identical question a little bit ago and then deleted it (while I was typing an answer)?

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me at all if `global.index` runs into a name collision somewhere.  Any use of globals here is bad, but that's a terrifically bad name for a global variable.

Comment: yes, this is just a sample code I use better names in my code. I deleted the old one because it works when the variable is not global but doesn't work when it is global. I was hoping for insight on why there is a 100,000 byte cap on global buffers and why its not documented anywhere.

Comment: I have a nodejs project that uses 15 megabyte buffers.  There's no 100,000 byte cap.

Comment: This code is not enough to reproduce the problem.  When I use a runnable version of this code, it works just fine for me (see the code I posted in my response below).  So, there's something else going on in your environment causing the problem.

Comment: Now your code shows `global.index = 0` in one file and `global.buff_idx` in another file.  If you can't show us an actual repeatable demonstration of the problem with real code, I doubt we can help further.  There are no fundamental limits around 100,000 bytes.

Comment: This whole global use of a buffer is an abomination.  Encapsulate the shared buffer in a module and just have each file that want's to use the shared buffer import your buffer module to get access to the shared buffer.  That's how you should be coding in node.js, not using globals like this.

Answer (score 0):

I have a project that uses 15MB buffers so 100,010 bytes is no issue at all.

I'm writing this as an answer just so I can show you the code I wrote and this code when run entirely by itself works just fine:

```
global.buff_idx = 0;
global.buff = Buffer.alloc(100010);

let data = "12345";

let bytes_written = global.buff.write(data, global.buff_idx);
global.buff_idx += bytes_written;
console.log(bytes_written);
```

It logs `5` which is what you would expect.

For us to help you further, you will need to post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

---

FYI, I also tried this same code split across two files like you show.  No difference.  There's something else causing the problem in your environment other than the code you show.

---

And, one more point:

This whole global use of a buffer is an abomination in node.js. Encapsulate the shared buffer in a module and just have each file that wants to use the shared buffer import your buffer module to get access to the shared buffer. That's how you should be coding in node.js, not using globals like this.

Comment: Thanks, I'll investigate.